# Force Closed captions on smartphones

Tags: android, iphone, youtube, smartphone, captions

I don't know if this kind of question can be answered here but here it goes.

I have some videos uploaded on youtube with closed captions. I'm using the yt:cc=on tag to force captions to be displayed always wich is what I want with the exception that using an Iphone the captions are just not being displayed.

Ipad works fine.

I have been looking through the web and I can't find anything.

Any help?

Thx.

Rubèn.

Comment: What player are you using? http://osxdaily.com/2012/06/06/enable-closed-caption-iphone-ipad-itunes/ And for YouTube http://www.translice.com/YouTube%20iphone%20app%20with%20closed%20captions-106.php

Comment: What do you mean? Youtube player? it is a mp4 video uploaded into youtube, and when I use an iphone to watch it the subtitles won't be shown even with the yt:cc=on tag. The subtitles are added via youtube closed captions tool.

Comment: Yes, what app are you using to play the file? the youtube app?

Comment: I'm using safari to open youtube. Also other people I know who did it with an Android phone have the same issue. So if people would be accessing the video with safari and maybe the youtube app, is there any code or anything that I can add in order to force those closed captions?